# Загрузка файлов PHP

Tags: php, backend

Код записывает файл правильно, но без расширения, подскажите как исправить?

```
<?php

require "db.php"; // подключаем файл для соединения с БД

$login = $_SESSION['logged_user']->login;
$var = R::findOne('users', 'WHERE `login`=?', [$login]);

if ($_FILES && $_FILES["userfile"]["error"]== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
{
    $name = "ava/" . $var->id;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $name);
/*    rename($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $var->id); 
*/}

header('Location: settings.php');

?>
```

Comment: Ты видишь чтобы в `"ava/" . $var->id` было какое-то расширение? Вот и я не вижу. так может ты его туда добавишь?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Загрузка файлов на сервер php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/338392/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-php)

Comment: Спасибо, я нашел необходимую мне строку, но пожалуйста запишите как это должно быть в связи с синтаксисом PHP, я в нём нуб )

Comment: А по аналогии с тем, что тут уже написано, тут две строки конкатенируются (складываются), надо сложить их еще с расширением

Comment: $name = "ava/" . $var->id . $_FILES['userfile']['type'];